# Командная строка

Tags: c#

Как использовать командную строку в C#? У меня windows 7. И меня не понятно назначение  командной строки.

Answer (score 4):

Использовать можно по-разному.

При сборке кода. [Построение из командной строки с помощью csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78f4aasd.aspx):

```
csc sample.cs
```

При выполнении кода. [Main() и аргументы командной строки](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/acy3edy3(v=VS.100).aspx).

```
public class Sample
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Число аргументов = {0}", args.Length);
       foreach(string s in args)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(s);
       }
   }
}
```

При запуске внешних приложений. [Process - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx).

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```